# Truncation of large table in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate

I would like to completely clear one table in my SQL Server database.

Unfortunately, the table is large (> 90GB). I am going to use the `TRUNCATE` statement.

The question is whether I should pay attention to something before?

I am also wondering if it will somehow affect the server's disk space (currently about 110 GB free)?

After all the action, `SHRINK DATABASE` will probably be necessary.

Comment: Truncation causes some trickle-down effect to the log (so will impact anything that _uses_ the log, like AGs, mirroring, log shipping, replication, CDC/CT, etc). Why will you need to shrink the database? Are you going to fill the table up again? So what's the point of taking back the disk space temporarily? If the table is no longer used, just drop it (but that has similar log impact). But shrinking is such a pointless exercise unless the database will never grow again.

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources
than DELETE with no WHERE clause,
but if you need even faster solution, you can create new version of the table (table1), drop the old table, and rename table1 into table.

R

Comment: DROP and TRUNCATE are pretty much identical in terms of resource usage. The practical difference is if you have permissions / triggers / etc. specific to the table, you'll have to re-create them, and you might not be able to drop due to other dependencies like schemabinding.

Comment: I had a few experiences when TRUNCATE was running longer than a minute, and had to be abended, and replaced with a DROP solution,
albeit on a different DB..

Comment: I suspect your experience also had other variables involved (e.g. blocking or metadata locks that didn't exist later when you tried to drop). They literally do the same thing in terms of logging (marks pages for deallocation), so I can't think of a single scenario in SQL Server where one would be measurably faster than the other if all else is equal.